# Filtering a noisy 1D time-series

Tags: time-series, signals, signal-processing, scientific-computing

I have a noisy, `1-Dimensional` time-series, which I'd like to filter so as to obtain the contained "signal". The time-series in question is a collection of timestamps, each of which corresponds to the time of some "detection". *Ideally*, these timestamps register only the "signal" of an instrument which emits pulses at some known period. The vast majority of data points, however, turn out to be noise.

I'd like to filter out the noise, so as to obtain *only* the subsequence of timestamps which correspond to the "real" detections (or close to it). I'm not concerned with the algorithm efficiency or time taken to do so. Again, the signal has a known period and, moreover, the signal was present for the entire duration of the portion of the data I'll be looking at. There could be, however, a small number of "missed" detections.

We can assume clock precision and accuracy.

I'm somewhat familiar with the filtering of `2-D` time series, however I'm not sure how to approach this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pick out at least one timestamp that you're sure is correct? Because then you could just reconstruct a noiseless timeseries like: (pseudocode)

```
timeseries = array(requisite_length)
for i from 0 to requisite_length:
    timeseries[i] = initial + i*period
```

If you don't one for sure, it is quite a bit more complicated. You essentially need to find an initial timestamp which maximizes the number of subsequent timestamps that fall on the period. You might be able to do that like this:

```
counts = array(length(timeseries)):
for i from 0 to length(timeseries):
    for j from i to length(timeseries):
        if floor(timeseries[j] - timeseries[i]) % period  == 0 OR ceil(timeseries[j] - timeseries[i]) % period  == 0:
            counts[i] += 1
start_idx = argmax(counts)

filtered_timeseries = array(counts[start_idx])
j = 0
for i from start_idx to length(timeseries):
    if floor(timeseries[i] - timeseries[start_idx]) % period  == 0 OR ceil(timeseries[i] - timeseries[start_idx]) % period  == 0:
        filtered_timeseries[j] = timeseries[i]
        j += 1
```

This snippit essentially counts the number of points falling within 1s (assuming the timestamps themselves are in seconds) of a whole number of periods from each possible starting point. It then loops over the original timeseries and copies each of the points it counted into a new filtered timeseries. You said you didn't care about running time, which is good because this is O(n^2).